# Adding Show Less/More link to Custom Post Meta

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

So,

I have a product post type with custom meta boxes. One of the meta box is for additional details. I show the custom post type inside other posts using a shortcode.

I can show the additional details on the frontend. When the details is kind of long I want to add a show more link which will show the rest of the details when clicked.

How do I do that?

Something like they have here. https://www.retailmenot.com/
When clicked on the 'More', full details are shown.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing, and the example you linked, is using javascript to toggle the display style attribute of a container div.

The example you linked is only using it when additional details are available, and they have placed them within a separate div to the description text, etc.

### The functionality works as follows:

We have a some `divs` with ids, and a `<span>` with an onclick calling our javascript function, `showHide()`. In this example, we are concerned with showing/hiding the `div` with id `showAndHide`:

```
<div id="somewrapper">
    <div id="always-visible">
        <span onclick="showHide()">Read More</span>
    </div>
    <div id="showAndHide">
        <p>This is the show-and-hide div.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

For the javascript portion:

We get the div by its id and set it to a variable, here `sh`. Then we check the state of `sh`'s style:display attribute. If it is `none`, the `onclick()` sets it to `block` to show it. If it has `block`, then it sets it `none`, *"hiding"* it.

All of that is done very easily in a few lines of code:

```
<script>
function showHide() {
    var sh = document.getElementById('showAndHide');
    if (sh.style.display === 'none') {
        sh.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        sh.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
</script>
```

[W3C gives a very clean example of this you can try in your browser](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_toggle_hide_show)

**As a sidenote**, you could achieve similar functionality with the css `visibility` attribute, but it behaves differently. `Display:none;` will not take up space, it is effectively removed; while with `visibility:hidden;` the element's place is preserved. That is unless you are dealing with `table` elements and using the `collapse` value. Since the example you linked **was not** using `tr`s, and the space **does** *expand*/*collapse*, I opted for `Display:Block/None`. 
[Read More on Visibility: visible/hidden/collapse here.](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp)

A [much more knowledgeable explanation on the differences between Display and Visibility](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp)

### Adding this functionality to a shortcode's output in wordpress

1) You need the id(s) of the element(s) you wish to show/hide.

2) If you're going to add a "read more" text and onclick, you will need to know either a) a measurable point at which to insert it in the containing div, or b) an element to which it can be [prepended](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_prepend.asp) or [appended](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_append.asp).

3) take the full javascript function(s), add them to a file, *myShowHide.js* perhaps, and upload it to your child theme's directory.

4) In *functions.php*, Register the script with [`wp_register_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/) and Enqueue it with [`wp_enqueue_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) to include that javascript file in your template pages. You can also wrap `wp_enqueue_script` in a function if you need it to only include the script on certain pages.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. I feel I can do it from here.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this for you meta box data:

Query your meta data with this:

```
<?php 
    $slider = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'posts_per_page' => 5,
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
             'meta_query' => array(
                         array(
                            'key' => 'your metabox key',
                            'value' => 'your metabox value',
                            'compare' => 'IN'
                        ) 
                    )


    ));

    if($slider->have_posts()) :
    while($slider->have_posts()) : $slider->the_post();
    $idd = get_the_ID();
?>

         <?php echo get_excerpt(); ?>
    <?php   

    endwhile;
    endif;



    ?>
```

And put this code into functions.php:

```
function get_excerpt(){

$excerpt = get_the_content();

$excerpt = preg_replace(" (\[.*?\])",'',$excerpt);

$excerpt = strip_shortcodes($excerpt);

$excerpt = strip_tags($excerpt);

$excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, 820);

$excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, strripos($excerpt, " "));

$excerpt = trim(preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $excerpt));

$excerpt = $excerpt.'.... <a href="'.get_permalink().'"  class="read_more"><h4 style="margin:0;">Details</h4></a>';

return $excerpt;

}
```

Comment: Hi Porosh,

Thanks for your answer. But I am not sure if I wanted that. I have updated my question. Sorry I wasn't elaborate before.

Thank you.